# Python error question: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

below is the code that I've written and I keep getting the error message in the title.
Please look through it and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#program name: circle.py
#program description: output should be user name, color of circle and area of circle with one decimal point
#programer's name: Trista
 
userName = input()

print('What is your name?')

color = input()

print ('What color is the circle?')

radius = input()

print ('What is the radius of the circle?')

pi = 3.1416

area = (pi*radius*radius)

round(area , 1)

print('Hello' + userName + ', the circle is' + color + ' and has an area of ' + area +'.')
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string value.  `pi*radius*radius` is attempting to multiply a floating-point number and two strings, which is meaningless.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you printed `What color is the circle?` _before_ you ask for the color.  You can include the message as part of the input statement: `name = input("What is your name? ")`

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs here:

```
area = (pi*radius*radius)
```

The variable `radius` came from an `input()`.  The `input()` function returns a string (`str`). You can't multiply strings with float numbers.

Just try casting the input to float instead:

```
radius = float(input())
```

I hope that I have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is "radius" is a string. When you use `input()` it returns a string, which you can change to other variable types such as `int` and `float`. Also, you can only concatenate strings so the last print statement would not work since the calculated area is a float.

```
#program name: circle.py
#program description: output should be user name, color of circle and area of circle with one decimal point
#programer's name: Trista
 

print('What is your name?')
userName = input()

print ('What color is the circle?')
color = input()

print ('What is the radius of the circle?')
radius = input()


pi = 3.1416

area = (pi* float(radius) *float(radius))

print('Hello' + userName + ', the circle is' + color + ' and has an area of ' + str(round(area , 1)) +'.')
```

Here's your code fixed, also watch the order of which you print so the user can see what they're inputting

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this code:

```py
#program name: circle.py #program description: output should be user name, color of circle and area of circle with one decimal point #programer's name: Trista

userName = str(input('What is your name?: '))
color = input('What color is the circle?: ')
radius = float(input('What is the radius of the circle?: '))

pi = 3.1416
area = pi*(radius**2)
areaString = str(round(area , 1))

print('Hello ' + userName + ', the circle is ' + color + ' and has an area of ' + areaString +'.')
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. Thank you. So float() keeps it as a number to be used in an equation and str() converts it to a number to be used in a sentence?

Comment: No worries! Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the error comes from the line

```
area = (pi*radius*radius)
```

`radius` is the return value of `input` which, according to its documentation, returns a string.  `pi` is a float.  As the error says, you can't multiply a float by a string unless the float is an integer (e.g., 5.0).  You need to convert `radius` to a float first.  I.e.,

```
radius = float(intput())
```